# Deserializing JSON numbers returning incorrect values

Tags: json, go, deserialization

I want to deserialize `json strings` with the go language. The value types of different keys are different. for example，in `string` `{\"category\":\"6\",\"cid\":2511993760745787586}`，`category` type is `string`, `cid` type is `int64`.

my code is as follows:

```golang
func main() {
    oriInfo := make([]interface{}, 0)
    pickled := "[{\"category\":\"6\",\"cid\":2511993760745787586},{\"category\":\"5\",\"cid\":2504429915944783937}]"
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(pickled), &oriInfo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    all := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0, len(oriInfo))
    for _, val := range oriInfo {
        m := make(map[string]interface{})
        for k, v := range val.(map[string]interface{}) {
            switch k {
            case "category":
                m[k] = v.(string)
            case "cid":
                m[k] = int64(v.(float64))
            }
        }
        all = append(all, m)
    }
    fmt.Println(all)
}
```

The results are as follows:
`[map[category:6 cid:2511993760745787392] map[category:5 cid:2504429915944783872]]`

Obviously，this is not what I want, because the result of `cid` are `2511993760745787392` and `2504429915944783872`, but my original `cid` are `2511993760745787586` and `2504429915944783937`.
In addition to using a struct, is there a better way?

Comment: _"Obviously， this is not what I want"_ – _What_ do you want? "_"is there a better way?"_ – Depends or what you want, you could use a struct to model the data, and unmarshal into a slice of that struct.

Comment: You're experiencing a float rounding error. Best not to use floats when you need int64.

Comment: "In addition to using a struct, is there a better way?" No. A struct is the best way for this. Is there a reason a struct is a problem? If so, please explain it so we can help solve that issue, too.

Comment: Is interface{} not a good idea?

Comment: `interface{}` is a good idea when it's needed. But you should generally use a concrete type whenever possible.

Comment: "Is interface{} not a good idea?" Of course not. interface{} is the worst idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be with a struct:

```
type myStruct struct {
    Category string `json:"category"`
    CID      int64  `json:"cid"`
}

var oriInfo []myStruct
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(pickled), &oriInfo)
// ... etc
```

This should solve your problem, since your problem is the result of [floating point rounding error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/13860).